# How to fix Google Chrome profile selection screen being corrupted since upgrading to Ubuntu Budgie 22.04 LTS?

Tags: google-chrome, budgie, ubuntu-budgie

Since updating to Ubuntu Budgie 22.04 LTS Chrome doesn't display properly anymore, and I get this instead of the profile selection screen which appeared upon launching:

[image: Google Chrome glitching out in Ubuntu Budgie]

Although it's happening in Chrome, this seems like a problem in the graphics subsystem of the OS itself. It shows something resembling the Firefox logo because I had opened Firefox a minute before. It seems to be displaying garbage from the previous uses of the OS.

How can I fix this? I already uninstalled and reinstalled Google Chrome and it shows the same glitched display.

Comment: If the problem is only occuring in one application, I can't see how you've come to the conclusion that it's a system wide problem. Have you tried uninstalling Chrome, deleting its application data, then reinstalling the software?

Comment: Well, as I already said in my question, I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome. And this problem happened only after upgrading the OS to LTS 22.04.